# In a private FB group, a girl said all moms in Area were racist. She contacted my employer. Can I be fired?

Tags: racism

Conversation continued with me asking on what grounds she had for such allegations, she would just continue to name call. She contacted my company and said she demanded I be fired. I took screenshots of the portions of the convo that I could get to. I blocked her. Removed my employer from my profile and contacted my boss and HR. Can I really be fired on baseless accusations?

Comment: What country/state are you in, what is your employment type?

Comment: United States, employer based in Ohio, I work remote in KS. I am Project Manager and work with individuals from all over the world, of all ethnicities/races

Comment: So you are a full time salaried employee?

Comment: Yes, I am full time salaried

Comment: No, not at all. I just asked her questions on how she could make such a generalization. I only said she was being immature and judgemental.

Comment: I even have the group admins post saying that I hadn’t said anything racist and that she was instigating

Comment: Usually if a young mother starts ranting at you you discount it as  stress. Soon enough they get distracted and either look after their kid or rant at someone else.

Comment: Keep us updated please. I'd eventually like to know your employer's answer to this question.

Answer (score 8):

When you say "a girl said all moms were racist", I imagine a fourteen year old. And if "all moms are racist" nobody can take that as serious evidence that you are racist. If you don't get complaints from co-workers, or from customers, with actual examples of racist behaviour, and if you don't behave in an unacceptable racist way in public, you'll be fine.

In this particular case, a random person demanding that you get fired will have very little effect. If you have screen shots where she claims that "all moms are racist", nobody can take her serious.

Comment: She is a mom in a bi-racial relationship (she disclosed, I did not know), this is a private “Mom” group. She, and the conversation, were deleted.

Comment: It's not likely that a single prison will be able to get them fired. However if the complainer gets some momentum via social media, the company is likely to drop them like a hot potato. That's just the way it works thesedays.

Comment: Momentum alone doesn't do anything. If there is a video of a badly out of context joke, or Twitter post, or whatever, sure. If it is just pure rage and demand, and there is no substance, then no. It really depends on what caused it.

Comment: @Nelson I would think it depends on the employer's determination of how much of a liability the employee is to the company achieving their business goals (or maintaining PR image) which we can't know. One company could react very differently than another.

Answer (score 7):

> Can I really be fired on baseless accusations?

Yes, unless you have a contract with your employer that protects you from being fired: "The Ohio Supreme Court has held... that the right of an employer to terminate an employee's employment for any cause at any time is absolute, and cannot be limited by principles that protect persons from gross or reckless disregard of their rights, or from willful, wanton, or malicious actions or acts done intentionally, with insult, or in bad faith..." [Employment-At-Will and Wrongful Discharge
in Ohio](https://www.lsc.ohio.gov/documents/reference/current/membersonlybriefs/132employmentatwill.pdf)

Most likely your employer won't fire you since there is no evidence but there doesn't have to be evidence. In most parts of the Internet it's a really good idea not to identify your employer or even use your full name.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry. If your company fires you based on somebody making a generalized claim, then talk to you lawyer to get a settlement fee, anyway that company is not  work to continue working for.

In the majority of the case:

- The person in question actually did not contact your employer just wants to threaten you

In the majority of the remaining cases and in a professional company:

- HR receives email from somebody ranting about one of your employees on facebook.
- HR briefly discusses with legal if the allegations are targeted against the company and not person (e.g. if the poor person wrote something: your hiring policies favor racists or "you dont care about racism")
- if yes, they may thing about a cease&desist regarding libel
- if no and they are in good mood, they may ask back if the person sending the email was experiencing this while you were on the job
- if no, they will inform the persons that they addressed this at the wrong place and that no further emails in this regard are desired
- If yes, they may ask for proof.
- If there is no proof or the proof is weak and unsubstential, they again may ask the person, potentially with a cease&desist to be careful what she says publically.

Comment: "Dear Ms. X: Be advised that someone is signing your name to stupid letters."